# deploying desktop app WCF endpoint

Tags: wcf

I have web-hosted client endpoint talking to desktop app service endpoint. this is the config on client endpoint side:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
<endpoint address="net.tcp://10.8.20.175:3337/NotificationService"
  binding="netTcpBinding" contract="INotificationService"
name="NetTcpBinding_INotificationService" />
</client>
<bindings>
<netTcpBinding>
 <binding sendTimeout="00:10:00" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"    name="NetTcpBinding_INotificationService"/>
 </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

and this is the config on service endpoint side:

```
<services>
<service behaviorConfiguration="NotificationServiceBehavior"
 name="NotificationService">
<endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="INotificationService" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:3337/NotificationService" />
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
</service>
</services>
```

I have tried to turned on service side WCF tracing by adding the following

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel"
          switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
          propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="sdt"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData= "C:\data\logs\trace.log" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
```

however, I am not getting trace.log generated.

so how do I get the tracing log on desktop app side? thanks!

Comment: Is your spesified path exuists? Folder shoud exists.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this:

```
<diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="false">
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
```

Under system.ServiceModel.

Try this guide [Setting WCF diagnostics quickly](http://petarvucetin.me/blog/2013/02/setting-wcf-diagnostics-quickly/)